# Is there a way to create a docker volume that isn't in the default location?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elastic-stack, elk

We currently run our docker ELK on dedicated slaves. Docker is taking up too much space due to indexes in ELK etc so we are looking to create a volume on a shared folder on the slave which has a much larger storage capacity. This is our docker-compose config

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"     
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"     
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
      - "5044:5044"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch


networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

I am having real trouble finding anything about this online or in the docs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you not mounting your elastic search data on shared storage?

Comment: Well, this is the exact question I am asking. I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: you have to mount shared storage on your docker host first and then use that path to mount on your elasticsearch container

Comment: Would you have an example of that or even point me at that in the docs? I cannot find it anywhere? Thanks.